# Angular httpClient post request sent repeated same parameter with blank value, Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular9

I'm using Angular Version 9 as frontend and rails API as backend. The problem is that when I created a POST request to server extra parameters with the same name is added at last. So RAILS doesn't detect the values inside the parameter I sent.

My code is:

```
   this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/accounts', {params: { 'account': {
        name: this.accountForm.controls.name.value,
        type: this.accountForm.controls.head_type.value.id,
        group_id: this.accountForm.controls.group_id.value,
        subgroup_id: this.accountForm.controls.subgroup_id.value,
        openning_balance: this.accountForm.controls.openning_balance.value
      }}).subscribe(
          res => {},
          error => {
              this.notifier.notify('error', error.error || error.error.message);
          }
        );
```

And when I get data in rails console there is extra parameter being sent.

```
 {"params"=>{"account"=>{"name"=>"", "type"=>"Asset", "group_id"=>"", "subgroup_id"=>"", "openning_balance"=>""}}, "account"=>{}}
```

Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: can't you just send it without wrapping it in extra params: `{params: { 'account':` ? like: 
`this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/accounts', { name: (...) }` ?

Comment: I removed params and it working now. Anyway thanks for the comment.